# "actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs" debug with VSCode

Tags: google-home

I successfully installed the "actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs" and it works well if i launch it using the command "node index.js" within the folder "...actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs\smart-home-provider".

I need now to debug some part of the code, thus i tried to debug it using VS Code as editor and with the launch.json configured like

`{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}`

When i launch the debugger all seems to start fine, but when i use the Google Chrome browser to access the main page (http://localhost:3000/) i get as response only "Cannot GET /".

It seems like the static route defined in the file "smart-home-provider-cloud.js" `app.use('/', express.static('./frontend'));`

isn't matched.

So i can't figure out why launching without debugging all works fine and if a start the debugger express returns only "Cannot GET /".

I would be grateful for any help or clue for further investigation !

Answer (score 0):

After long digging i found my issue. The config file for debugging was missing a config line.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}/smart-home-provi
     }
]
```

}